# Socket connection fails to send data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have a long running TCP connection. A machine (IoT device) establishes a connection with the server, connection is setup (encryption and stuff) and data stored, connection is kept open a while.

Everything kind of works but sometimes the server 'drops' the connection with an error:
**An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine (code: 10053 - ConnectionAborted).** But the connection isn't dropped, cause server can read data from the device after the error and could start sending again. If the connection drops in real, both the server and client need to reinitialize connection (security and stuff).

There is nothing really that indicates why network stream cannot be written to.
And polling the socket says, that it's writetable, and in next point it throws an exception. Seems to happen randomly.

```
public class ClientIdentifier
{
    ...
    public TcpClient Connection { get; set; }
    public BlockDecoder ConnectionDecoder { get; set; }
}

private void ReplyToClient(ClientIdentifier client, byte[] data)
{
    byte[] encrypted = client.ConnectionDecoder.Encrypt(data);
    var stream = client.Connection.GetStream();

    int dataIndex = 0;

    while (dataIndex != encrypted.Length)
    {
        if (CanWriteClient(client))
        {
            byte[] block = encrypted.GetChunk(dataIndex, Frame.BLOCK_LENGTH);

            stream.Write(block, 0, Frame.BLOCK_LENGTH);

            dataIndex += Frame.BLOCK_LENGTH;
        }
    }
}

private bool CanWriteClient(ClientIdentifier client)
{
    try
    {
        return client.Connection.Client.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectWrite);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Warn(ex, $"[{client.HexIdentifier}]: Polling client write failed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT (12.11.2017)**

Server: 192.168.1.150
Device: 192.168.1.201

I can see that the device sends RST when the server resets Seq and Ack in some weird way.

[image: Device Error]

Comment: The server application must be re-opening the socket after closing the socket.  The client will not automatically reconnect.

Comment: That's not the case, they can connect... but the communication fails sometimes and the question is why. The code above tells that "Write if you can and wait if you cannot" - and it fails.

Comment: What you describes sounds like a miracle. The only hypothesis comes to my mind is that you have some connection layer that re-establishes connection to the server. I think it would be helpful for you is take packet trace on server with wireshark or tcpdump

Comment: Are you sure the server drops the connection and not the client?

Comment: The device manufacturer tells us that our server sends out a TCP RST packet... and if i remember right socket exception with code 10053 comes from the host machine (server) and ...54 is a remote ?

Comment: Added some Wireshark capture. Maybe this can clear something up.

Comment: The packet above the one marked in red seems to make no sense at all.

Comment: RST seems to be fine as server response is weird.
Client -> Server: SEQ 6017 ACK 753 (OK)
Server -> Client: SEQ 753 ACK 6129 (OK)
Server -> Client: SEQ 1 ACK 1 (What the heck??)
Client -> Server: SEQ 1 ACK 17 [RST] (OK... i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the mistake. Timeout was set to way too low.

```
... 
TcpClient client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

int timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).TotalMilliseconds;

client.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
client.SendTimeout = timeout;
...
```